# edit UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, iphone, camera

I work for an app they use the Camera. So I implemented an Overlay with my own buttons. But now I have a Problem. My Problem is how can I edit the UIImagePicker that he makes a photo in a specific area like old Photo Booth.

In this App you can make photos from Person and you can give them a new look. When I make a photo in a specific area the result is the full screen photo from my iPhone.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks!

update:

I have this code:

```
- (IBAction)getPicture:(id)sender 
    {

    customCamera *cameraController = [[customCamera alloc] init];
    cameraController.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    cameraController.delegate = self;

    cameraController.showsCameraControls = NO;
    cameraController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    cameraController.toolbarHidden = YES;


    UIImageView *cameraOverlayView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage   imageNamed:@"Ausschnitt2.png"]];

    cameraOverlayView.alpha = 1.0f;

    cameraController.cameraOverlayView = cameraOverlayView;
```

But this is for an Overlay. When I take a Photo I see my Overlay but when the photo is recorded I can see the original iPhone screen not the photo with the Overlay. My question is, how can I make a photo like photo booth or anyone with other objects in the screen.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more clearer, like providing some screenshots of what you would like to achieve / what you have already implemented.

Comment: Hi Unheilig. to you speak German?

Comment: weisst du zufällig wie ich das Overlay mit dem Foto verbinden kann? Das Overlay wird mir zwar angezeigt aber das fertige Foto ist trotzdem der gesamte Bildschirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to modify the image, you need to

- access the individual pixels of the images and process them as needed, or
- use CoreGraphics to render your image and then draw an overlay, or an effect on top of it, or
- use -renderInContext to take what you see on the screen and make a UIImage out of it (but this means you are limited to the resolution of your overlay and the camera image below).

I'd recommend you do some reading on Quartz and CoreGraphics, and look at some of Apple's dames like [RosyWriter](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html), which take images and place graphics on top.

Edit: Here's a quick and dirty code that shows how to draw a rounded rect on top of an image, and then draws some text inside that rect.  This is a method on the underlying UIImage:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size);
[self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height)];
[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:.5] set];
UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:roundedRect cornerRadius:10.0];
[path fill];
[textColor set];

[textString drawInRect:textRect
              withFont:font
         lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail
             alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample Code. I installed this on my iPhone and works. So I will similar the same in my photo app except the pink background color. I this app the user can make a video with a pink background. How can I implement this in my app with my custom background? How can I use point 1 of your answer?

Comment: What you see is not a pink background color, but a change to the pixels to make the red portion of the pixel more prominent.  Your code wouldn't just do that to every pixel, it would just change the pixels in locations where you want them, in whatever way you want.  
If you don't want to manipulate pixels, then look at this sample which should let yo unmake changes using CoreGraphics:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011190

Comment: This is a very nice app. really crazy what we can to with the iPhone. Face detection and it works fine but I think you understand me. So let me explain what I will to with the app. I use tesseract (recognize text from a photo) I will not recognize all text which is on a site but only 1 line or 2 lines. I made a specific rectangle for the line in my cameraOverlay. But when I show the picture in my imageView that show me all what is on the screen behind the overlay. I only need one or two lines from the text not all.

Comment: I added some code that might help you get started. Study Quartz for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should I implement this code in my getPicture function or should I create a new function?

Comment: I'm not sure what the structure of your app is.  If you're already displaying things onscreen using your overlay, then keep that and use this when you export the image.  Also it's always better to keep things in independent methods than to overload a method with to many tasks.

Comment: I finally made it in 6 days I can draw a red rectangle on the photo. :-) Can you possibly tell me how I can now use the text in the rectangle?

Comment: '[textString drawInRect:textRect
              withFont:font
         lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail
             alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];'

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! But I think you misunderstood me. My text that I have photographed with the camera is now in my red rectangle. My question is, how can I now cut out the text which is in my red rectangle?

Comment: You know where the rectangle is, so you have to extrapolate to the size of the original image, and crop. Search for UIImage+Crop to find a UIImage category that will do the cropping for you.

Comment: Great.  Please go ahead and select this as the correct answer.  :-)